# TypeScript: conditional type inside the same type/interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im trying to get some conditional typing to work and not sure if what Im thinking is possible to do or not. Here it goes:

```
type AParams = {
    hello: string

}
type BParams = {
    world: string
}

type Data = {
    name: "a" | "b",
    data: AParams | BParams
}
```

Depending on `name` being `a` or `b` I want to enforce the `data` to either have type `AParams` or `BParams`, respectively. Any way this can be accomplished with TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two different interfaces for the two cases like:

```
interface AData {
    name: "a",
    data: AParams
}

interface BData {
    name: "b",
    data: BParams
}
```

and then set `Data` using union types like:

```
type Data = AData | BData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Data` type can be next instead:

```
type Data = {
    name: "a"
    data: AParams
} | {
    name: "b"
    data: BParams
}
```